# Replacing Small Angles in a Polygon with Bigger Ones

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

I have the vertex data of a 2D polygonal region that contains the position of each vertex. My task is to calculate the angles throughout the polygon and replace the vertices with small angles (let's say smaller than 120 degrees) with bigger ones. For example, if three points (ABC) make an angle of 90 degrees, I want to replace the middle point (B) with another one that makes 120 degrees with the other two points.

**I want to know if I can write an algorithm to find a new position of the vertex B, given the x-y coordinates of A and C and the 120 degrees angle between ABC** (I calculated the current angle so you don't need to write how to do that). Note that, I am not looking for a unique point (there is no unique point), just looking for an angle calculation to replace the point. If you know other methods to do this kind of replacements, they are welcome too.

Comment: the problem is, making one angle bigger makes the two angles beside it smaller, so a greedy local algorithm like this will likely not work. also, the sum of internal angles in a polygon is constant, so you may not be able to achieve an arbitrary target angle.

Comment: You may assume that input data consist of 500+ vertices, borders of a country or a lake if you may.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a triangle ABC with B the "small" angle that you want to replace with a larger angle. Call the new location B'. Here is the construction. Let D be the midpoint of AC, i.e., D = (A+B)/2. You want to place B' on the segment BD.
Any location along BD will result in a larger angle at B', with an angle of 180 when B'=D.

Pick a parameter t in [0,1]. Then place B' = (1-t) B + t D.

---

[image: ABC]

---

Now, there is a flaw here (besides that pointed out by *spug*). It may be that moving B to B' causes AB'C to hit other
parts of the polygon, and so it is no longer simple. You'll have to decide whether you want to compute a t that is guaranteed not to cause self-intersection.

Comment: Using the middle point approach, it shall guarantee that B' will be left inside the triangle. I don't have to handle every edge case so it shall be good enough. Also if I fix the angle that AB'C makes to 120 degrees, do you know a way to calculate t in the parametric equation?

Comment: @CanBayar: I would solve the equation of the dot product of (B'-A) . (B'-C). That equals their lengths times the cosine of 120, which is -1/2. It is a bit of a messy calculation. Or you could just use binary search along BD: t=0.5, then t=0.25 or t=0.75, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, the dot product does not end up with a unique result and I couldn't find a way to include the middle point in the equation. Binary search was easier to implement, thanks for your help.